# URL returned a bad HTTP response code / 401 authorization required in Facebook Share

Tags: facebook

Here's what I tried for Facebook Debugger tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdevstmaws.linesofphp.com%2Fvideo%2Findex%2F52f0fd544eab99ae28000106

Scrape Information:

```
Response Code   401
Fetched URL http://devstmaws.linesofphp.com/video/index/52f0fd544eab99ae28000106
Canonical URL   http://devstmaws.linesofphp.com/video/index/52f0fd544eab99ae28000106
Warning
Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
Bad Response Code   URL returned a bad HTTP response code.
Warning
Errors That Must Be Fixed
Missing Required Property   The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
Notice
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
URLs
Graph API   https://graph.facebook.com/1419346681640654
Scraped URL  See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL
```

The URL that I would like to share is: http://devstmaws.linesofphp.com/video/index/52f0fd544eab99ae28000106

What could be the reason? It's not scraping my site anymore.

```
Scraper response: Document returned no data
```

Meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://devstmaws.linesofphp.com/static/img/logo_facebook.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Check out my awesome video!" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Check out my awesome video!" />
<meta property="og:description" content="SearchTheMusic gives you the ability to legally add music to your videos and share them with the world!" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://devstmaws.linesofphp.com/video/index/52f0fd544eab99ae28000106" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has to be able to access the URL for the Open Graph tags to work, and your URL is protected by a password. Only public URLs are possible. You get the same error as if you cancel the authorization popup.

Comment: Thanks! But before it worked in my another staging server. URL: http://muserk.sourcepadstage.com w/ authorization too. I was confident enough that it will also work in my another staging server but I got 401 authorization required.

Comment: it surely did not really work, but the password protection on your staging server does not return an error - it just keeps asking for a password. which is annoying, because you cannot close the browser tab that easy...

Answer (score 0):

I give you other way also. Here I remove javascript SDK.Other are all same
    Taken intermediate step.
    So I take this steps:
     I have created folder , outside of project folder(password protected).i.e. outerface.And create a file,say projectfront.php
     First: 
        defined a outside url
    Here, I have used aforesaid file path. So now Facebook can't abuse me.

```
<?php 
 $faceproject_url='[your servar path]/outerface/projectfront.php'; 

?>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $faceproject_url; ?>" data-type="button_count"></div>

 Second:
 In outerface/projectfront.php-
I have written(with proper doctype) as:
......
........
<script>
function xyz()
{
url=[Give your target link];// it will your project page, which you want to share.
window.location=url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="xyz()">

<?php 
ob_start(); 
?>
Please wait....
</body>
</html>
[please do proper html]

So now if any user click on your share button, share'll be successfully done and Facebook will not obstacle us. Also If you click on link on Facebook(in wall) after share, you will redirect successfully to your link defined in projectfront.php.

Thanks
Atanu Mitra
```

Comment: You should remove your one answer. as both are same

Answer (score 0):

You usually receive this error when the fetched URL to the page and the OG:URL do not match.

Answer (score -1):

Using javascript SDK for Facebook
I have overcome with intermediate step.
    My project url is also password protected.

So I take this steps:

1. I have created folder , outside of project folder(password protected).i.e. outerface.And create a file,say projectfront.php
2. Call a function using Facebook sdk and use `FB.ui({ with method:feed`. And I have taken a tricks. In link, I have used aforesaid file path. So now Facebook can't abuse me.

> ```
>  <div><a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "sharesend()">share</a></div>
> <script>
> function sharesend()
> {
>   FB.ui({
>      method: 'feed',          
>      link: '[your servar path]/outerface/projectfront.php',
>      picture: [give picture, if you can],
>      caption: [give any caption],
>      description: [give any description],
>           .....................,
>           ..............
>     }, 
>     function(response){}
>      );
> }
> </script>
> ```

In **outerface/projectfront.php**- I have written(with proper doctype) as:

```
......
........
<script>
function xyz()
{
url=[Give your target link];// it will your project page, which you want to share.
window.location=url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="xyz()">

<?php 
ob_start(); 
?>
Please wait....
</body>
</html>
[please do proper html]
```

So now if any user click on your share button, share'll be successfully done and Facebook will not obstacle us. Also If you click on link on Facebook(in wall) after share, you will redirect successfully to your link defined in projectfront.php.

Thanks
Atanu Mitra